# PowerShell Select-Object Sub-Object with Where Clause

Tags: powershell

Sorry for the bad naming, I really can't wrap my head around exactly what I am asking for.

If I run this:

```
Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName bob.bobbington@bob.com |
    select UserPrincipalName, {$_.StrongAuthenticationMethods.MethodType},
           {$_.StrongAuthenticationMethods.IsDefault}
```

I get back this:

```
bob.bobbington@bob.com
{PhoneAppOTP, PhoneAppNotification, OneWaySMS, TwoWayVoiceMobile}
{False, True, False, False}
```

Is there any way for it to return me just the True MethodType from StrongAuthenticationMethods sub-object?

So a return like this:

```
bob.bobbington@bob.com
PhoneAppNotification
```

I trying to avoid running a lengthy runtime script to loop through each user if I can return the data I need in a single pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a calculated property:

```
Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName 'bob.bobbington@bob.com' |
    Select-Object UserPrincipalName, @{n='AuthenticationMethod';e={
        $_.StrongAuthenticationMethods |
            Where-Object { $_.IsDefault } |
            Select-Object -Expand MethodType
    }}
```